# Why does this code result in 0?

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    uint32_t Ex;
    Ex=(x<<1)>>24;
    cout<<Ex<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but it gives 0 for any value of x?

My task is the following:

```
Computation of the biased exponent Ex of a binary32 datum x.
```

Comment: What are your inputs? Have you tried all numbers? What edge cases have you tried? The code actually multiplies x by 2 then divides the result by 2^24. So it would have to be relatively large to be none zero. But any number greater than 2^23 and a lot of negative numbers should return none zero. Note this is an educated guess as I don't have pencil and paper to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not so much that you get zero for 'any value of x' but that you get zero for any positive value of x smaller than 0x01000000 (which is 16777216).

None of this helps much with explaining a 'biassed exponent of a binary32 datum'.  That sounds like the exponent of a 32-bit floating point (IEEE) number.  You probably have to worry about endianness of the representation, amongst other things.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting zero because you're right shifting 24 bits which is shifting your significant bits off the end and replacing them with zeros from the left.